# Why can't I `tail` the result of a `tail` on a Perl 6 list?

Tags: raku, seq

Why can't I `tail` the result of a `tail`? I can call `head` on the sequence `tail` returns (and other variations), but a `tail` on a `tail` doesn't work (in 2017.10):

```
> my $list = <a b c d e f g h i j>;
(a b c d e f g h i j)
> $list.head(5).head
a
> $list.head(5).tail
e
> $list.tail(5).head
f
```

This one fails:

```
> $list.tail(5).tail
Nil
```

But throwing a `list` in there works:

```
> $list.tail(5).list.tail
j
```

Comment: It would seem that because `tail` returns a `Seq` type and `Seq` does not have a `tail` method on it, you must first convert it to a list (either with `.list` or `.List`) before you can call the subsequent `tail` method on it. But it doesn't make sense why it works for `head`...

Comment: I just tried `$list.tail(5).tail(1)` and it works, but just not with `$list.tail(5).tail`. Why does the default parameter not work in the second case?

Comment: Thanks for catching up to my question ;)

Comment: `.tail` and `.tail(1)` are implemented with `Rakudo::Iterator.LastValue` and `Rakudo::Iterator.LastNValues` respectively, which differ quite a bit in implementation. https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Rakudo/Iterator.pm#L1807 - here's the problematic one.

Comment: i figured out what's wrong: tail on the `List` takes an iterator and skips it ahead `$n` items. then, the tail method on `Seq` calls `count-only` on it to figure out how far to skip ahead to get the last `$m` items. However, `count-only` on the first iterator just gives you the total number of items in the original list. It should probably either signal an error when asked for `count-only`, or it should calculate the proper amount of items left.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug.

The `.count-only` optimization method for `List.iterator` did not account for the fact that the iterator may already be partially consumed (here, by the first `.tail` call) when the method is called and, as timotimo++ pointed out in the comments, kept always returning the original length. The argless `.tail` then [used that method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/9c04dfc4a427da11f5762534e4601fe697b9e127), hitting the bug.

This is now fixed on `2017.11-76-gf70e20b` Rakudo

Unless I'm misunderstanding iterator protocol, the same bug [was present](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/af9812fa73) in quite a few other iterators, so thanks for finding this hive!

Comment: Further fixes in 0e228fab8a0b6e91f001 and 854c10c27e49041c87841